# Json Unmarshaling in Golang

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I want to unmarshal the followng json in golang. I am not able to access the inner data .
What is the best way to do it?

```
{
  "1": {
    "enabled": 1,
    "pct": 0.5
  },
  "2": {
    "enabled": 1,
    "pct": 0.6
  },
  "3": {
    "enabled": 1,
    "pct": 0.2
  },
  "4": {
    "enabled": 1,
    "pct": 0.1
  }
}
```

I use

```
type regs struct {
        enabled bool    `json:"enabled,omitempty"`
        pct     float64 `json:"pct,omitempty"`
    }

var r map[string]regs
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jStr), &r); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", r)
```

but i dont see the values inside the struct.
Result: `map[1:{enabled:false pct:0} 2:{enabled:false pct:0} 3:{enabled:false pct:0} 4:{enabled:false pct:0}]`

Comment: Hi MagicWand, you need to [export the fields](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) to be able to unmarshal the json. Fields that begin with a lowercase letter, including an underscore, are considered unexported which means they are not accessible outside of the package in which they were declared, and because of that the `encoding/json` package has no access to the fields that you declared in your package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Marshaling and Unmarshaling, you should define struct field as exported field, also the destination should be map of regs.
Also the bool type is not valid for the `Enabled` and you should change it to int

```go
type regs struct {
    Enabled int     `json:"enabled,omitempty"`
    Pct     float64 `json:"pct,omitempty"`
}

func main() {

    a := `{
        "1": {
          "enabled": 1,
          "pct": 0.5
        },
        "2": {
          "enabled": 1,
          "pct": 0.6
        },
        "3": {
          "enabled": 1,
          "pct": 0.2
        },
        "4": {
          "enabled": 1,
          "pct": 0.1
        }
      }`
    dest := make(map[string]regs)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(a), &dest)
    fmt.Println(dest)
}
```

The output will be:

```go
map[1:{1 0.5} 2:{1 0.6} 3:{1 0.2} 4:{1 0.1}]
```